# Can Interface method implementation "skipped" in Go?

Tags: go

I am not sure if "skip" is the right way to describe what I see:

```
type Container struct {
    clck         sync.Mutex
    closed       bool
    cli          *client.Client
    ID           string
    IO           io.ReadWriteCloser
    closetimeout time.Duration
}

func (c *Container) Write(dat []byte) (int, error) {
    return c.IO.Write(dat)
}

func (c *Container) Read(dat []byte) (int, error) {
    return c.IO.Read(dat)
}
```

It seems to me `Read` and `Write` method are not implemented. What does this called in Golang?

Answer (score 2):

If you're talking about the `Container` type, the `Read` and `Write` method implementations are already shown in your code. You cannot define a method for a type without implementing it. With those methods, `Container` now implements `io.Reader`, `io.Writer`, and `io.ReadWriter` interfaces. The `Read` and `Write` methods of `Container` simple delegate the operation to the `ReadWriteCloser` pointed to by the `IO` field. `Container` does not implement `Close` method, so it is not a `io.ReadWriteCloser`.

If you're talking about `c.IO.Read`, those methods are called using an interface. When you create a `Container` instance, you have to set `c.IO` to a struct that implements `io.ReadWriteCloser`, and when `c.IO.Read` is called, the method on that struct will be called. For instance, an `os.File` implements `io.ReadWriteCloser`, so you can:

```
file, err:=os.Open("filename")
ctr:=Container{IO:file}
```

After this, `ctr.Write` will write to that file.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, both methods are implemented and their implementation calls the methods of IO. Note that you can change the implementation however you want, or add lines before or after the request there.

However, interestingly "skipping" can be achieved by anonymous fields. In this case, if you make:

```
type Container struct {
    io.ReadWriteCloser
    clck         sync.Mutex
    closed       bool
    cli          *client.Client
    ID           string
    closetimeout time.Duration
}
```

the methods of io.ReadWriteCloser will be carried out to Container struct.

However, if you forget to put a ReadWriteCloser to the struct it will panic, so try to not use it unless you know what youre doing. (Example: https://play.golang.org/p/ak7qpaWSE8n)